# angularjs - remove currency filter parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am using currency filter inside custom filter in `ui-grid` to format the cell data. Please find below my code.

```
HelperServices.filter('getQuantFormat', function($filter) {
    return function(val) {
        if (val == 0)
            return;
        else
            return ($filter('currency')(val, "", 2));
    }
});
```

Here currency filter adds parenthesis for negative values. I want to use currency filter without parenthesis for negative values.

**How do I remove parenthesis from currency filter?**

Comment: Perhaps, by using `.replace(/[()]/g,'')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to write a customCurrency filter. Which takes care of the negative values. Something like below :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.filter('customCurrency', ["$filter", function ($filter) {       
    return function(amount, currencySymbol){
        var currency = $filter('currency');         

        if(amount < 0){
            return currency(amount, currencySymbol).replace("(", "-").replace(")", ""); 
        }

        return currency(amount, currencySymbol);
    };
}]);
```

So whenever you amount is less than zero, you can replace the parenthesis with the negative sign.

Hope this helps :)