# Angular showing parenthesis for negative number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing some math on my template and sometimes the result is a negative number.
My problem is when the result is a negative number, it shows a parenthesis wrapping it. How can I solve it ? **using Angular 1.2.**

my controller:

```
                    $scope.totalToReceive = totalToReceive;
                    $scope.discountedTotal = discount;
                    $scope.antecipatedTotal = antecipatedTotal;
                    $scope.totalReceived = totalToReceive - discount + antecipatedTotal;
```

my template:

```
<li>
    <span class="big-number"><span>R$</span> {{ totalReceived | currency: ""}}</span>
</li>
```

Update:
I tried to write my own filter, but it did not work

```
.filter('numeric', function(){
return function (value) {
    if (value < 0) {
        value = '-' + Math.abs(value) + '';
    }
}
})
```

Comment: That's what the [currency filter does](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)... If you want different behavior, you'd need to write your own filter.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I tried. I will update my question.

Comment: Strip the parenthesis filter can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532393/angularjs-remove-currency-filter-paranthesis

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Quite simple. Just writed a new filter:

```
.filter('customCurrency', ['$filter', function($filter){
return function (amount, currencySymbol) {
    var currency = $filter('currency');

    if(amount < 0) {
        return currency(amount, currencySymbol).replace("(", "-").replace(")", "");
    }
}
}])
```

template:

```
<span class="big-number"><span>R$</span> {{ totalReceived | customCurrency: ""}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and below is how I solved mine.

I create a method in my angular service (this allows me to call the function anywhere I need it)

```
formatNegativeVal(value: any){
  if(value.substring(0,1) === '-'){
    console.log('valusss ', value)
    return "(" + (value.replace(/-/g, '')) + ")"
  }else{
    return value;
  }
}
```

Then I just create another method in whatever component I need to use the above method.

```
formatNegativeVal(value: any){
    return this.common.formatNegativeVal(value);
  }
```

And Finally I just call the last create function and pass the whole currency value in the HTML page.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="credit_balance">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Balance Credit </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      {{formatNegativeVal(element?.credit_balance  | currency : configs?.money_symbol 
      + ' ':'symbol':'1.0-0')}} 
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Javascript method toLocaleString with the "currencySign" option:

```
const x = -123;
console.log(x.toLocaleString('en-US', { 
  style: "currency", 
  currency: "USD",
  currencySign: "accounting" 
}));

// ($123)
```